# Resistor switching methods

Tags: resistors, switching, voltage-measurement, cost, resistance-measurement

I have an application where I need to measure the voltage drop over a resistor that varies between 10 ohm - 50 kohm. As I have this set up as a voltage divider, with the result being read by an AtoD, I thought the best way to be accurate is to switch in different resistors, depending on the resistance of the variable one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fygaxx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Something like the above. This needs to be controlled by a microcontroller, and my initial thought was to use a multiplexer to switch in the different resistors. This seemed like a good idea at first, however, when looking through the datasheets of these components, the ON resistance was a problem. For the higher ranges, it was negligible, but if the 100R resistor was in, the on resistance of the MUX was significant enough to affect the result.

This is a budget controlled design so all of the very low on resistance MUX/decoders etc. are out of the budget (I am not in control of this).
My next thought was to perhaps use MOSFETS to switch in the resistors as these can be extremely low with on resistance, however, this takes us more port pins on my microcontroller. 4 rather than 2. This would leave me with only 2 I/O pins left, which doesn't leave much room for adding anything else that may be requested in the future. This method also means more components, which slightly adds to the placement cost.

Is there a better way to do this that I am missing? Or are the MOSFETS perhaps the best way to do this?

Comment: Decoder and mosfets

Comment: @Kartman I did mention budget a few times in the question. It needs to be a cheap solution. Yes, the components don't cost much, but when hundreds or thousands are being made, I'm being asked to stick to a tight budget. Adding more components to the solution won't work

Comment: If you explain the application a bit better than "measure voltage drop across a resistor" I am sure people can recommend solutions that are far simpler than the depicted one.

Comment: @tobalt I don't think it needs more. That is essentially what it is doing. Measuring the voltage drop over something that has a varying resistance depending what it is measuring. Doesn't matter whether this is a thermistor, FSR, whatever, it is still measuring the drop over a change in resistance

Comment: @MCG so you are essentially trying to measure the unknown resistance ? Because everything else is put in by your circuit (VCC, series resistors, switching)

Comment: @tobalt sure, put it like that if you prefer

Comment: @mcg ‘cheap’ is relative. define your definition of cheap so we can have something to work with. You can get dual mosfets in sot23, so that mitigates your placement cost.

Comment: @Kartman It's difficult to define exactly, but the entire budget is below £30. This also includes the casing, PCB, placement, components, manufacturing time etc, so I can't put an exact number on it for the components

Comment: What accuracy and sample rate do you require?

Comment: @Damien accuracy is 2% max, 1kHz sample rate

Comment: @MCG how many bits of noise free resolution does your ADC have at that sample rate?

Comment: Use 4 ADC channels. Drop the voltage divider and instead connect each resistor as "shunt" to ground. Make sure to have an accurate current source. Activate one channel at a time.

Comment: @Lundin don't have enough available unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

More cost efficiency (this feels like code golf):

- only 1 control line
- only 1 transistor (N JFET or P MOSFET), 1 R and 1 C
- infinite number of possible measurement ranges
- can get rid of the ADC, if it isn't needed otherwise (see below)
- needs calibration and could be temperature dependent, but the same goes for the switched R method at a lesser extent (so it depends on your desired level of accuracy)
- 1kS/s is ambituous with an MCU (needs fast control clock)

[image]

How does it work:

By controlling the duty cycle of control, you vary the DC gate voltage and therefore tune the resistance of the FET in a continuous fashion. You can also use feedback to bring AtoD to some defined voltage (e.g. VCC/2) and then your Duty cycle gives you the value of R1 (via a conversion which you have to establish once).

Down the road, you could even scrub the ADC (save costs) and realize the feedback with a comparator, so your MCU can read the duty cycle directly.

Comment: The ADC does have a buffer on the input, it just wasn't important to the question to put it in here as that isn't the part of the circuit I am focusing on. Adding in another component like a MUX as well as the MOSFETs isn't a good solution as it adds extra cost to the design as mentioned in the comments

Comment: Ok, that gives me an idea of the level of cost-sensitivity you are talking ;)

Comment: With the edit, where does the infinite measurement ranges come from? You are still just switching a FET which was one of my earlier thoughts? As to calibration, this will be done, as well as having temperature compensation for ambient temperatures between -10°C to +50°C

Comment: By controlling the duty cycle of control, you vary the DC gate voltage and therefore tune the resistance of the FET in a continuous fashion. You can use feedback to bring AtoD to VCC/2 and then your Duty cycle gives you the value of R1 (via a conversion which you have to establish once)

Comment: Code golf should be used more often in other fields of engineering. Not as a goal in itself but as a method to question complexity and cost.

Comment: @winny I think minimalism is a wonderful design principle. Only add more when strictly mandated by requirements.

Comment: Ahh I see. Still very early in the morning! +1 for this, I'll stick this circuit into the next prototype and see how it works. If no other solutions come up, I'll accept this in a couple of days. Cheers for the response!

Comment: Isn't it easier to mention PWM?

Comment: @winny absolutely I think that is a great idea. I'm usually doing this at work as everything needs to be cost effective so I need to get to the most minimal solution possible before adding things only if I have to

Comment: @MCG I recommend doing some quick spice sims beforehand to get a feeling of what transistor will work for this, which depends on your VCC and on the accuracy with which you can vary the duty cycle. especially for MOSFET the knee is rather sharp. For JFET you get a more gradual response, but their low end resistance is not as low.

Comment: @PaulGhobril I think PWM is too special. you could end up doing analog first order Delta-Sigma instead if you scrub the ADC. Also PWM gives you rather low precision for a given control clock.

Comment: I'll definitely be doing simulations first. Luckily, when it comes to prototyping, the budget isn;t as much of an issue so I can design a couple of different methods into it and try multiple solutions

Answer (score 3):

If your microcontroller has tri-state I/O pins, you may not need transistors to switch the resistors. Just use three IO pins and switch them between high (output) and high-impedance (input) mode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx2bbC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can use variants of this circuit with the resistors in parallel or on the low side, etc.

Also look into whether your microcontroller has configurable series resistors built into the pins that you could rely on to dispense with the lowest value resistor.

[EDIT] You may need to adjust the resistor values to stay within the current capabilities of your microcontroller. Maybe you can get sufficient accuracy with just 2 pins and 3 resistors down to 470 Ohms.

Comment: This microcontroller doesn't have tri-state pins unfortunately, however, it's a good idea, so still +1

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements (2% accuracy @ 1 kHz sample rate) are relatively high; because of this I think I would avoid 'tricks' that require oversampling, and stick to using MOSFETS to switch in the resistors.

But if you want to lower costs you may be able to get away with fewer than 4 resistors, depending on the effective noise-free resolution of your ADC at this sample rate:

[image]

Note that this is just looking at a 2% resolution, not necessarily 2% accuracy. But with a 16-bit ADC you may be able to get away with a single 680 Ohm resistor (no need for any switching). With a 12-bit ADC two resistors may be enough. With a 10-bit ADC, you probably need three.

Note that you don't need to switch out the highest calibre resistor — you can just switch in a lower resistor in parallel. So if you use 2 resistors, you only need one MOSFET, etc.

Comment: Another good idea. +1 again! I'll be designing all of these into the next prototype so I can test each of them. Which program did you use to make that graph? Or was it a graph you found somewhere?

Comment: @MCG I used python: https://gist.github.com/damiendr/ed47eafa26b4ef938d66d16c6e2031e1

Answer (score 1):

Another very low cost way. While the original one can get rid of the ADC and save a lot of cost, it may not be able to achieve 1kHz of bandwidth if the Control Clock of the MCU is too low.

Here is another solution that requires the ADC, but uses zero control lines and realizes a logarithmic resistance measurement. Part costs should be well below 50c. The output voltage will be proportional to the log of R over some decades. As the accuracy requirement is modest, the logarithmic single range solution should be fine.

[image]

If the current through D1 and R1 is too large for small R values, then a two transistor current sink can be wrapped around R1. This will also make the circuit more temp stable and use less current for minimum added cost.

The gain settings resistors R2 + R3 have to be chosen according to the diode and VCC range.

The diode can also be "under" R1, with the gain working vs GND instead of VCC. This has the advantage that the output signal will be GND referenced ( in case the ADC is not using VCC as reference)